# How do you use MooseX::Declare with a subclass of Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

Let's say you've done something like the extending recipe [3](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.24/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Extending/Recipe3.pod) or [4](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-1.24/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Extending/Recipe4.pod). So you have some class like MyApp::UseMyBase that you can use in place of 'use Moose;' in your normal Moose-using code. But how do you use MyApp::UseMyBase when using MooseX::Declare?

I can see MooseX::Declare::Syntax::MooseSetup::import_symbols_from() which might be promising, but have no idea how to change its return value and have MooseX::Declare use and import from MyApp::UseMyBase instead of Moose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to subclass `MooseX::Declare::Syntax::Keyword::Class`, and possibly also `MooseX::Declare::Syntax::Keyword::Role`, if that's what you want, and customise `import_symbols_from` in there.

Then you extend `MooseX::Declare` itself to actually provide your modified keywords. For that, you'll need to customise the `keywords` method. You can either replace the ClassKeyword and RoleKeyword instances returned by it with instances of your customised keywords, or just make it set up the new keywords under a different identifier, depending on whether you want

```
use MyMooseX::Declare;
class Foo { ... } # the modified class keyword
```

or

```
use MyMooseX::Declare;
class   Foo { ... } # the default class keyword
myclass Bar { ... } # the modified class keyword
```

[CatalystX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CatalystX-Declare) contains prior art in doing this, but it's also much more complicated than what you're asking for. I'm not aware of a simpler example of this, but I'd love to include improved documentation on this in case you're feeling like sharing your solution with the rest of the world